# Two questions about proof in Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres about "integration on manifolds"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

How does auther prove the equivlence between two definition?

How does auther prove that it suffices to prove the simple case where the support of f is contained in some coordinate patch?

In this chapter, I feel many details are omited and hard to read. Is there some similar book can help me learn these knowledge?

[image]

[image]

Comment: He would use a partition of unity to reduce to that case by writing $f$ as a sum of functions whose support is contained in a coordinate patch. Actually this result is better understood via measure theory. $dV$ is a measure on $M$, so you can break up integrals as stated.